# Does a normal contract accepts WETH or I have to do something special for it?

Tags: blockchain, tokens, erc-20

I have built a smart contract that works with Ethereum will it work with WETH ?
And if it will what should I do  change in my smart contract.
Sorry to sound like a noob . Can you gibe me some guidance ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to register WETH's contract address within your own and have the contract withdraw the token from the user's wallet, given approval. You should probably have this done in the constructor/ hard code it in and have it stored in a global variable so that YOUR contract may interface with WETH directly.

e.g. "IERC20 public WETH = IERC20(0x...);"

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please ?

Comment: look at this contract https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/finance/PaymentSplitter.sol